# UINavigationBar in iphone 6s and in iphone x

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am building an app

the navigation bar in iphone 6s behind navigation bar but in iphone x it is perfect , can anyone please advice me what is the problem

here are screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you programmatically set the position in the code?

Comment: no, I am building it using UI builder

Comment: Create an on-site [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Please use safe area layout guide from your storyboard